# MVC3, turn off field validation for a field not in a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a Form in an MVC3 project.  One of my input fields should accept HTML.  Unfortunately I cannot have a ViewModel which this value maps to.  The Field is autogenerated and read in automatically.  I am getting the following error.

```
  A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

Since there is no viewmodel, I cannot apply the [AllowHTML] attribute.  Does anyone know a workaround that does not involve disabling validation for the entire page?

Thank You

Additional Information:
I can access the unvalidated value by doing the following:

```
 using System.Web.WebPages;
 using System.Web.Helpers;

  .....Inside Controller....
  string value = Request.Unvalidated("input-40");
```

The problem now is that the Request.Params collection throws an exception.  I would like to access all the other values and have them be validated...just not that one.  Is there a way for me to validate the other fields either explicitly or access a validated collection.

The following would be fine

```
  string value = System.Web.Something.ValidateInput(Request.Unvalidated("input-41"));
```

Unfortunately I don't know where/if this method exists

Comment: If it's an argument to the action, I think you can decorate the argument with AllowHTML though I'm not positive.

Comment: I think you could use [ValidateInputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) to decorate the action, but that's going to affect the whole form collection.

Comment: Decorating the action is fine if I can figure out how to call validation on the other field values manually.  Any ideas?  I'd be looking for something like System.Web.ValidateInput(Request.Params["input-name"])

Comment: @AFrieze Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426854/how-to-call-validationattributes-manually-dataannotations-and-modelstate) question will point you in the right direction.

Comment: See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/05/23/security-issue-in-asp-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection yourCollection)
{
    // your stuff
}
```

Comment: This would turn off validation for all form values.  This is ok if there is a way for me to call validate on each value manually. Is there?

Comment: Well, depends how you pass your viewmodel/values to the action. These are your options: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx), but you may not find what you're after :(

Answer (score 0):

Use ValidateInput attribute for your action method. Seems to be unsafe but should work, cannot test it now.